# identifying patterns in CSV columns/rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi all and thanks for help in advance.

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows:

I have two columns within one CSV file: Column A and Column B.

There are certain patterns that need to be present in my data in each row underneath column A and B.

For example, if there is a "1" in row 1 of column A , there must be a "5" adjacent to it in row 1 of column B.

If there was a "1" in row two of Column A, and a "2" adjacent to it in row 2 of column B I would need this to be flagged and printed out as "does not follow pattern"

The rules go as follows:

- Any time theres a 1 in column A, next to it there should be a 5 in column B
- Any time theres a 3 in column A, next to it there should be a 6 in column B
- Any time theres a 2 in column A, next to it there should be a 4 in column B
- Anytime these rules are not followed a return statement should say "pattern not followed"

Here is where I am at on the code, I can't seem to figure out a way of doing this data check.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os  # filepaths
import glob
import getpass  # Login information


unane = getpass.getuser()

# Paths:
path2proj = os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'Users', unane, 'Documents', 'Home','Expts','TSP', '')
path2data = os.path.join(path2proj,'Data','')
path2asys = os.path.join(path2proj,'Analysis', '')
path2figs = os.path.join(path2asys, 'figures', '')
path2hddm = os.path.join(path2asys, 'modeling', '')

df = pd.read_csv(path2data + '001_2012_Dec_19_0932_PST_train.csv')

os.chdir(path2data)

# extension = 'csv'
# all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

all_filenames = glob.glob("*.csv")
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames]) 
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

df = pd.read_csv(path2data + 'combined_csv.csv')
df['left_stim_number'].equals(df['right_stim_number'])
df = pd.read_csv(path2data + 'combined_csv.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['left_stim_number'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['right_stim_number'])
df1['match'] = np.where(df1['left_stim_number']== df2['right_stim_number'], True, False)

# Checking to see if there are any errors as all should add up to 7
df1['add'] = np.where(df1['left_stim_number']== df2['right_stim_number'], 0, df1['left_stim_number'] + df2['right_stim_number'])

# def see_correct(df):
#    if df1['add'] == ['7']:
#        return 1
#    else: 
#        return 0
    
# df1.tail(10)

combined_csv.isna().sum()
combined_csv.dropna()

df.loc[df['left_stim_number'] != df['right_stim_number'],:]






---

Example of CSV data

A(left_stim_number)        Column B (Right_stim_number)
1                 5

1                 5

3                 6

1                 5

3                 6

2                 4

2                 4

2                 4

1                 5
```

Comment: Can you show some part of `combined_csv.csv`, with col names?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't have access to your csv file so it will be hard to help. Please include a minimal example df1 and df2 - just enough to illustrate the problem (`df.head(somenumber)`).  Please take the time to read [mre].

Comment: Just added an example of the CSV file. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't have an example I'll make one up - a pandas DataFrame with two columns of integers.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':np.random.randint(0,10,100),
                   'colB':np.random.randint(0,10,100)})

>>> df.head()
   colA  colB
0     8     7
1     8     1
2     6     9
3     2     2
4     8     1
```

There might be more concise ways to do this nut this is pretty clear what is happening. This uses a lot of [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Your rules exclude any row in `colA` that is not 1,2,or 3. Rows in `colB` that are not 4,5,or 6 are also excluded.  You can make a mask for all the excluded rows.

```
mask = ~df.colA.isin([1,2,3]) | ~df.colB.isin([4,5,6])

>>> df[mask].head()
   colA  colB
0     8     7
1     8     1
2     6     9
3     2     2
4     8     1
>>>
```

You can use the mask to assign "pattern not followed" to a new column for all those rows.

```
df.loc[mask,'colC'] = 'pattern not followed'

>>> df.head()
   colA  colB                  colC
0     8     7  pattern not followed
1     8     1  pattern not followed
2     6     9  pattern not followed
3     2     2  pattern not followed
4     8     1  pattern not followed
```

You can also use the mask to find all the rows that **might** match your criteria. Notice `colC` is `NaN` for these rows.

```
>>> df[~mask]
    colA  colB colC
13     3     5  NaN
35     2     6  NaN
39     1     5  NaN
61     2     5  NaN
62     1     5  NaN
65     1     6  NaN
69     1     5  NaN
70     2     4  NaN
77     3     5  NaN
92     1     6  NaN
98     2     5  NaN
>>>
```

Set `colC` the rows that meet the criteria to True(?).

```
df.loc[(df.colA == 1) & (df.colB == 5),'colC'] = True
df.loc[(df.colA == 3) & (df.colB == 6),'colC'] = True
df.loc[(df.colA == 2) & (df.colB == 4),'colC'] = True
```

That leaves some outliers.

```
>>> df.loc[df.colC.isna()]
    colA  colB colC
13     3     5  NaN
35     2     6  NaN
61     2     5  NaN
65     1     6  NaN
77     3     5  NaN
92     1     6  NaN
98     2     5  NaN
```

Which can be fixed with.

```
df.loc[df.colC.isna(),'colC'] = 'pattern not followed'
```

---

After looking at that **only** the last four operations are needed.

```
df.loc[(df.colA == 1) & (df.colB == 5),'colC'] = True
df.loc[(df.colA == 3) & (df.colB == 6),'colC'] = True
df.loc[(df.colA == 2) & (df.colB == 4),'colC'] = True

df.loc[df.colC.isna(),'colC'] = 'pattern not followed'


>>> df.loc[df.colC == True]
    colA  colB  colC
39     1     5  True
62     1     5  True
69     1     5  True
70     2     4  True
>>>
```

---

If the text in csv file looks like this-

```
4,9
8,3
4,6
2,4
7,5
1,3
 .
 .
 .
```

The Dataframe can be made with -

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',names=['colA','colB'])
```